# mysql index on timestamp column

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have 4 columns in table..one of which is unix timestamp column.

Case 1:
I have composite index(INDX_1) on all 4 columns which makes cardinality of INDX_1 100% of number of rows since timestamp is unique for each row..

---

Case 2:
I have composite index (INDX_1) on first 3 columns and timestamp column is separately indexed (INDX_2). Cardinality of INDX_1 is 30%-40% of number of rows and for INDX_2 it is 100% of rows.

---

Is there index duplication of first 3 columns in case 1 because its timestamp which make cardinality 100% of rows. If yes, is it bad?

Or case 2 is efficient?

My understanding is that there will be more index scanning in case 1 than case 2.